# Left numbering equations in LaTeX

Tags: numbering, align

I am trying to number equations on the left, while still keeping them left-aligned in LaTex.

I use this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{align}
EQUATION HERE
\notag
\end{align}%
```

I've also tried `equation` and `eqnarray` in place of `align`, but neither combination is successful in numbering the equations on the left hand side. They are always numbered on  the right hand side.

Comment: With `\notag` you get no number at all. The example with `\notag` removed has the number on the left also with `equation` (which is recommended for single line displays).

Comment: the fragment you show can not be run (no `\begin{document}` please fix it show that it shows the problem.  But you need `fleqn` option for left aligned equations, the `leqno` option that you use will put the equation on the left for `equation` and `align` (and `eqalign` but don't use that)

Answer (score 1):

With `\notag` you get no number to begin with.

This has numbers on the left; note that `align` should not be used for single line displays.

```
\documentclass[11pt,leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

This has the number at the left
\begin{equation}
EQUATION HERE
\end{equation}
and also this one
\begin{align}
a&=b\\
c&=d
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you also want left alignment for displays, add the `fleqn` option.

```
\documentclass[11pt,leqno,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

This has the number at the left
\begin{equation}
EQUATION HERE
\end{equation}
and also this one
\begin{align}
a&=b\\
c&=d
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Never use `eqnarray`.